# Как посчитать всевозможные комбинации строки

Tags: c#, алгоритм, математика

Допустим, есть словосочетание: "Пример задачи". Задача - заменить русские буквы на аналогичные английские.

1. П**р**имер задачи
2. Прим**е**р задачи
3. Пример з**а**дачи

Как посчитать общее количество таких замен в строке?

Comment: @herberus, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Мне нужен алгоритм) Мне не нужно готовое решение

Answer (score 1):

1. Составляете таблицу возможных замен.
2. Для каждой буквы строки выясняете, возможна ли для неё замена. Подсчитываете количество букв, которые можно заменить
3. Количество всевозможных комбинаций — `2^N`, где `N` — результат из предыдущего пункта.